# Output of matplotlib.pyplot.hist produces NaN values and does not plot

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure if this has been asked before, I couldn't find a previous question referring to this.

I've been working with a dataset producing histograms. The x data and the weights I'm using don't contain NaN values but the output when run through plt.hist() it produces NaN values. Code and output below:

```
plt.hist(log10(x), density = True, weights = y1)
print(plt.hist(log10(x), density = True, weights = y1))

[Out] (array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]), array([0.8376793 , 1.37634814, 1.91501699, 2.45368584, 2.99235469,
       3.53102353, 4.06969238, 4.60836123, 5.14703007, 5.68569892,
       6.22436777]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
```

This code has previously worked with other datasets but this one just doesn't want to comply. I ran some code to check for NaN values in x and y1 and there aren't any in either. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `log10(x)` contain `NaN`s by chance? I.e. does your data contain negative numbers?

Comment: No my data is all positive. I've just taken out negative values from my weights but it's still giving me ```NaN``` values.